# How to compare LARGE Multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I searched and searched over this foro and this question is not in it, please help me with this if someone can.

I have two LARGE multidimensional arrays with the following formats

```
$arr1 = array( array (n1,n2,..,n=5), array (n1,n2,..,n=5), n-arrays (n1,...,n5) )
```

**Note**: the subarrays of arr1 have 5 numbers each .

```
$arr2 = array( array (n1,n2,..,n=4), array (n1,n2,..,n=4), n-arrays (n1,...,n4) )
```

**Note**: the subarrays of arr2 have 4 numbers each .

Now, I need to remove from `arr1` the sub-arrays that include the sub-arrays in `arr2`. Please, see below an example:

**With this two arrays:**

```
$arr1 = array(array(1,2,6,8,10), array(2,4,6,8,10), array(20,40,60,80,100));

$arr2 = array(array(1,6,8,10), array(200,400,600,800));
```

**The code must return:**

```
$ret = array(array(2,4,6,8,10), array(20,40,60,80,100));
```

Because the numbers of `(1,6,8,10)` are in `(1,2,6,8,10)`

This is that code that I'm using now, and it works, but for a limmited number of data.... I think I need something more efficient

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $a ) {        
   foreach ($arr2 as $a2) {                     
      if ( count(array_diff($a, $a2)) == 1 ) { 
         unset($arr1[$key]); break; }        
      }     
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if all elements were removed during `array_diff()`

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $v1) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $v2) {
        if (empty(array_diff($v2, $v1))) {
            unset($arr1[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

print($arr1);
```

Or if your sticking with `count()`, you can change it to something like

```
if ( count(array_diff($a2, $a) < 1)) { // array_diff has the $a2 first
    unset($arr1[$key]); break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, none of this options yo gave works for me... "count(array_diff($a, $a2)) == 1"  is exactly what the code needs to do.